# INDUCTION why is this a valid proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I have a problem to understand k in the following induction proof.

> Prove that $3^n -1$ is even for any natural number $n$.

Is there anybody that can show me that this is a valid proof and what is k in this case?
\begin{align}
\tag{Basis}  3^0-1&=0 \\
\tag{Basis} -3^1-1&=2 \\
\tag{Induction step} \text{For $n\geq2$} \qquad 3^n-1&=3\cdot 3^{n-1}-1 \\
&=3\cdot(3^{n-1}-1)+2 \\
&=3\cdot 2k+2 \quad \text{where $k \in\mathbb{Z}$} \\
&=2\cdot(3k+1) \\
\end{align}

Comment: What is it meant to be a proof by induction *of*?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to show $2|(3^{n-1}-1)$.  If so the induction step would be assuming that there is an integer $k$ such that $2k=3^{n-1}-1$ with $n \ge 2$

Comment: Proof that $$3^{n}-1$$ is an even number for all natural numbers

Comment: Proof of *what*?  Please state what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It looks like you have some confusions about how to use MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to. In addition, you'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If a number is even, then it is divisible be 2. So the proof is equivalent to showing that $2|(3^{m}-1)$ . That just means that 2 is a factor of $3^m-1$ which means that there must be some integer that you can multiply to 2 to get you the $3^m-1$

Comment: Okay thanks....

Comment: But you didn't say _what_ you are trying to prove...

Comment: So always k is an random integer and n is how many step/times, right?

Comment: Have you ever done a "Proof By Induction"?

Comment: See [Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) : it is a proof technique aimed at proving that "property" $P(n)$ holds for every *natural* number $n$. The proof needs two steps : *Basis* : prove the case for $n=0$, i.e. prove that $P(0)$ holds. *Induction step : **assuming that** $P(n)$ holds, prove that $P(n+1)$ holds.

Comment: In your case, you have to prove that "$3^n-1$ is *even*, for very $n$". You have proved $P(0)$. The secon line in your proof is wrong and unnecessary. The next step is the *Induction step* : assume that $3^n-1$ is even and prove that $3^{n+1}-1$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but it looks like this is a proof of the fact that numbers of the form $3^{n}-1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are even, meaning they can be expressed as $2k$ for integral $k$. The base cases, the second of which is both superfluous and and mistakenly has a negative in front of the $3^{1}$, show directly that this holds for $n = 0,1$. In the inductive step, it is proven that the claim holds for $n$, assuming that it holds for $n-1$. As you can see, the quantity $3^{n} - 1$ is - after a string of algebraic manipulations including the substitution $3^{n-1}-1=2k$ are performed - shown to be equal to twice an integer. In my mind, an easier proof would be to note that $3^{n}$ is always odd, and thus $3^{n} - 1$ is always even, but maybe this is more a demonstration of the technique of induction than of its result.

Answer (score 0):

It's is a valid proof but badly explained:

Claim:  $3^n -1$ is even.

Case $n = 0$.  $3^0 -1 = 0$ is an even number.

Case $n = 1$ we don't actually need to do this step but $3^1 -1 = 2$ and even number.  (Presumably that negative sign is a typo.)

Induction Step:  $n \ge 2$.  *AND* we assume that we have already shown that $3^{n-1} -1$ is an even number.  (As we have already done for $n =0$ and $n=1$).  [The written proof never stated that we are making that assumption.  If one is familiar with induction proofs it goes without saying, but for a novice it should be pointed out.]

Now for $n$:

$3^{n} -1 =$

$3*3^{n-1} - 1=$

$3(3^{n-1} -1) + 3 -1 =$

$3(3^{n-1} -1) + 2 =$

Now we assumed we have shown $3^{n-1} -1$ is an even number.  Let's call that numbe $2k$ and substitute it in.

$= 3(2k) + 2 = $

$6k + 2 = $

$2(3k + 1)$.  ANd that is in even number.

So if $n = 2$ and we know $3^1 -1$ is even we know $3^2 - 1$ is even.  ANd if $n =3$ and we know $3^2 -1$ is even we know $3^3 -1$  is even.  And if $n = 4$ and we know $3^3 -1$ is even we know $3^4 -1$ is even and so on forever.

The inductive step lets us go on forever.

....

That's the basic proof by induction.

1) Base Step: You show it for the first case.

2) Induction step:  You show that if it is true of one case it will be true for that next.

Implication: You realize that if one case implies the next, and you have a first case, that means you have proven the second... and therefore the third.... and therefore the fourth .... and therefore every case.

====

FWIW

I'd do it this way.

Base case:  $n = 0$

$3^0 -1 = 0$ and even number.

Induction step:  Assume we know that $3^n -1 = 2k$ an even number. We will prove $3^{n+1} - 1$ is an even number:

$3^{n+1} - 1 =$

$3*3^{n} - 1 = $

$3(3^n -1) + 3 - 1=$

$3*2k + 3 - 1=$

$3*2k + 2 =$

$2(3k + 1)$ is an even number.

Implication:  We have shown this is true for $n=0$.  We have shown if in it true for $n$ it is true for $n +1$.  So it is true for $n = 0+ 1= 1$; and for $n = 1+1=2$; and for $n=2+1=3$; and so on for all non-negative integers.